# Regular expression which should not allow special characters and numbers except underscore

Tags: regex

I have used one regular expression which should not allow special characters and alpha numeric also. So i tried with this

```
String targetPage="Prestige$%$lll.jsp";
  String pattern1 = Pattern.compile(".*[0-9].*").toString();
  String pattern2 = Pattern.compile(".*[$!*&+,:;=?@#%'()^|-].*").toString();
  System.out.println("**** pattern1 is "+pattern1);
  System.out.println("**** pattern2 is "+pattern2);
  System.out.println("****"+targetPage.matches(pattern1));
   System.out.println("**&&&**"+targetPage.matches(pattern2));
 if ( targetPage == null || targetPage.matches(pattern1) || targetPage.matches(pattern2) || "".equals(targetPage) || (!targetPage.endsWith(".jsp") && !targetPage.endsWith(".xml")) ) 
 response.sendRedirect("/register.jsp");
```

Its working fine. But with certain scenarios like the above one, i mean $%$ its failing.

Any help is highly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have some special characters in `pattern2` that need to be esacped in order to match the literal like so : `\\$`

List of special characters that need to be escaped: `[]\^$.|?*+()`

Comment: When i am using \. in java its giving error, so how to handle in java for that

Comment: Great information on Java Regular Expresisons: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html. There's a section specifically on escaping characters, too.

Comment: You need two backslashes `\\$`